# Aligning images in doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I am writing a doc file in doxygen, and I included an image by doing

```
\image html screenshots/enabled.png "caption"
```

This shows my enabled.png image on the generated documentation. However, I would like the image to be aligned to the left (since the rest of the documentation is that way). Is there any way to do this in doxygen **without** doing it with inline html or css?

Comment: Not an answer, but I think the easiest way is still to change the CSS file [like in this So question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759077/how-can-i-change-the-position-in-my-html-of-the-created-graph-by-graphviz-if-i-a).

Comment: @Sonson123 : yes, this is indeed the easiest way :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the following HTML syntax works on Doxygen 1.8.6 (tested with Firefox 66):

```
/*! \mainpage Test
 *
 * <img src="my-image.jpg" align="left">
 * <div style="clear: both"></div>
 *
 * This is a test page.
 *
 */
```

Doxygen wraps the image in a `<div class="image">`, but the `align` property overrides centering. The extra clearance `<div>` is added to avoid having the following text written to the right of the image.

Comment: I hope you made a typing error in the version 1.8.6 is very old (December 2013). The current version is 1.8.16.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="myimage.png" align="left"/>
```

But you may need to add \n chars afterwards to prevent text wrapping to the right of the image.

html only as well

Answer (score 0):

Stuffing the image into an aligned Markdown table seems to work:

```
| Image description |
| :---- |
| \image html image.png |
```